# Password reset django 1.6

Tags: python, django

I have just updated my django installation to 1.6 from an older version.

My urls.py file contains the following:

```
url(r'^user/password/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',name='password_change'),
url(r'^user/password/done/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done',name='password_change_done'),
url(r'^user/password/reset/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', name='password_reset'),
url(r'^user/password/password/reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^user/password/reset/complete/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete', name='password_reset_complete'),
#url(r'^user/password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'),
url(r'^user/password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm_uidb36', name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

Been trying to allow users to reset their password, however i am getting the following error when an email address is submitted:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': 'xxxxx', u'token': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

(the x's have been changed for the question)

The django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm def is here:

```
# Doesn't need csrf_protect since no-one can guess the URL
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@never_cache
def password_reset_confirm(request, uidb64=None, token=None,
                           template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html',
                           token_generator=default_token_generator,
                           set_password_form=SetPasswordForm,
                           post_reset_redirect=None,
                           current_app=None, extra_context=None):
    """
    View that checks the hash in a password reset link and presents a
    form for entering a new password.
    """
    UserModel = get_user_model()
    assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None  # checked by URLconf
    if post_reset_redirect is None:
        post_reset_redirect = reverse('password_reset_complete')
    else:
        post_reset_redirect = resolve_url(post_reset_redirect)
    try:
        uid = urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64)
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, UserModel.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        validlink = True
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = set_password_form(user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(post_reset_redirect)
        else:
            form = set_password_form(None)
    else:
        validlink = False
        form = None
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'validlink': validlink,
    }
    if extra_context is not None:
        context.update(extra_context)
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, context,
                            current_app=current_app)
```

When using the commented url as opposed to the url below it, the following error results:

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': 'xxxxx', u'token': u'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$']
```

Comment: Can you show us your view "password_reset_confirm"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first keyword parameter name of the view is `uidb64` but you are passing `uidb36` in the keyword arguments dict. Change your URL patterns and use the commented version. The method signature has changed in version 1.6.

Looking at your error message again, I think it's not an issue in your URL configuration, rather either in a view or template where you use reverse URL resolution. This is the `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` method or the `url` template tag. You are probably passing there a keyword argument with the key `uidb36` which needs to be changed to `uidb64`.

Comment: Please see revised question.

Comment: Hi Bernhard, how would i change that?

Comment: In my password_reset_email.html file template i didn't have the proper URL. Which should be `{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}`

Comment: Is you problem solved then? If so, would be great if you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Edited

Why is this line commented? :

```
#url(r'^user/password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

Comment: Have tried to use both `uidb64` and `uidb36`. Same results.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going on here.

I had in my templates folder a registration/ folder with code only supported by previous versions. So i updated it with 1.6.5 template files.

Also, not updating the admin files caused problems.